# django celery unit tests with pycharm 'No module named celery'

Tags: django, unit-testing, celery, pycharm

my tests work fine when my target is a single function (see 'Target' field in the image):

```
questionator.test_mturk_views.TestReport.submit
```

However, when I specify my target to include all tests within my questionator app:

```
questionator
```

I get this error:

> Error ImportError: Failed to import test module:
>   src.questionator.test_mturk_views Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
>       module = self._get_module_from_name(name)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in
>   _get_module_from_name
>       **import**(name)   File "C:\Users\Andy\questionator_app\src__init__.py", line 5, in 
>       from .celery import app as celery_app  # noqa ImportError: No module named celery

Note that my tests include my settings via 'Environment variables' (see this in the pic too):

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=questionator_app.settings.development;PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

The celery [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/django-celery/en/2.4/cookbook/unit-testing.html) mentions a "Using a custom test runner to test with celery" but this is in the now defunct djcelery package. I did though copy/paste/tweak [this mentioned test runner](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/contrib/test_runner.py%5C) and used it as described, but I get the same error.

Unfortunately using CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER also does not work http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager

I would appreciate some guidance. With best wishes,
Andy.

[image]

Comment: depending on the order the tests are run, and the order of your settings, a test might be trying to load the celery modules before it's available. Usually tests are run in alphabetical order, so make sure anything that runs before `.test_mturk_views.` would be able to load the Celery stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with-the-same-problem (most likely me),

I had followed the official [tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) for getting celery working in my project. They advised the below:
[image]

Just making the last import explicit solved my problem:

```
from taskapp.celery import app as celery_app  # noqa
```

I'll see if I can nudge Celery's creators to update their tutorial ([pull request](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3463)).